# Function of comparison coq

Tags: coq

I want to make a function of natural numbers comparison in coq 
I declare a Set of invariant contain sup, inf, egal

```
Inductive invr:Type:=inf | sup | egal.
```

And I define a function comparaison

```
Definition comparaison (inv:invr)(a b:nat):bool:=
  match invr with
  |inf => if (a < b) then true else false  
  |sup => if (a > b) then true else false 
  |egal=> if (a = b) then true else false 
  end.
```

But it does not work! Thanks for your response.

Comment: "it does not work" is not a proper way to explain your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to match type (set) invr with its constructors values instead of variable inv, so you get an error

> The term "invr" has type "Set" while it is expected to have type 
>   "invr".

You need to do the matching for `inv`, not `invr`

```
Definition comparaison (inv:invr)(a b:nat):bool:=
  match inv with
  |inf => if (a < b) then true else false  
  |sup => if (a > b) then true else false 
  |egal=> if (a = b) then true else false 
  end.
```

Also make sure that you have <, >, = notations are defined to return bool, because by default they return `Prop`, which can't be used in if/else. So you need to use beq_nat, and leb from Arith.

Simplified final version (removed redundant if/else branches).

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Inductive invr : Type:= inf | sup | egal.

Definition comparaison (inv:invr)(a b:nat):bool:=
  match inv with
  |inf => leb a b
  |sup => leb b a
  |egal=> beq_nat a b
  end.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical beginner mistake.

`<` stands for `lt`, which has type:

```
lt : nat -> nat -> Prop
```

That is, `a < b` is just a proposition, not a procedure that computes whether `a` is less than `b`!
The same goes for equality.

What you want to use is a function that computes the truth of these propositions, either as a boolean or as a richer type:

In the library `Arith`:

```
beq_nat: nat -> nat -> bool
leb: nat -> nat -> bool

(* or the more informative versions which return proofs of what they decide *)
eq_nat_dec: forall n m : nat, {n = m} + {n <> m}
lt_dec: forall n m : nat, {n < m} + {~ n < m}
```

So the following is a valid expression:

```
if beq_nat a b then true else false
```

Also note that the following is a valid expression equivalent to the precedent one (since `beq_nat` returns a `bool`):

```
beq_nat a b
```